# JPA 2.0 @Version column not getting incremented

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

I am forced to ask my question on this forum after spending close to 8 hours, searching all over the web (including SO), to no avail. My question is related to [JPA @Version field doesn't get incremented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321280/jpa-version-field-doesnt-get-incremented), but there are some differences.

My set-up: Java, JPA 2.0, DataNucleus 3.1.3, Google App Engine SDK 1.9.17.

I have a data model, User, which has a field annotated with @Version, as follows:

```
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;
import org.datanucleus.api.jpa.annotations.Extension;

@Entity(name="User")
@Table(name="User")
public  class       User
    implements  Serializable    {

    private static final long serialVersionUID  =   -6706180854431454626L;

    public  User()  {
    }

    @Id
    @Column (name="USER_IDEN_PK",nullable=false)
    ....
    ....
    @Basic  (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column (name="USER_LAST_LOGOUT_TIMESTAMP",nullable=false)
    private Long    userLastLogoutTimestamp =   null;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    public void setUserLastLogoutTimestamp(Long userLastLogoutTimestamp) {
        this.userLastLogoutTimestamp = userLastLogoutTimestamp;
    }

    public Integer  getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
```

The following is the code where the User entity gets updated. The paramUser parameter is the updated User entity, that needs to be persisted in Google App Engine's High-Replication Datastore.

```
    public  synchronized    User    updateUser  (User   paramUser)
                            throws  Exception   {
        User    existingUser    =    null;

        existingUser    =   getUserByUserIden(paramUser.getUserIden());
        logger.info("exst ver = " + existingUser.getVersion().intValue());
        logger.info("param ver = " + paramUser.getVersion().intValue());
        if(null != existingUser)    {
            modifiedUser    =    tu.getEM().merge(paramUser);
            tu.getEM().flush();
        }
        logger.info("new ver = " + modifiedUser.getVersion().intValue());
        return modifiedUser;
    }
```

Here is what happens:

- Initially, the "version" field has a value = 1. A User entity is read
  from the database and displayed on the screen.
- Some attributes of
  this User entity are modified.
- An attempt is made to persist this
  entity.
- The "paramUser" has all the unmodified as well as modified
  fields.
- The code first "find"s the entity, and, as per my
  expectation, I get a "1" printed against "exst ver".
- The code then prints "1" against "param ver", which too, is as per my expectations because I am NOT supposed to modify this value.
- The code then "merge"s the "paramUser" entity. This method returns the updated User entity, which I save in "modifiedUser".
- Finally, I flush the Entity Manager.

Here is the question: Against "new ver", I still get "1", whereas it was my expectation that I would get a "2". Even in the underlying GAE datastore, the value of "version" remains "1".

What is it that I need to do to make JPA/DataNucleus/GAE/High-Replication Datastore increment the "version" field by 1, when I call the "merge" API?

Any help/insights/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Here is the log:

```
2015-07-08 21:57:33.147

com.applix.imedipro.serverapp.controller.UserController update: paramJSONUser = {"userIden":"someUserIden","userPassword":"someUserPassword","userName":"someUserName","userMobile":2222222222,"userStreet":"someUserStreet","userArea":"someUserArea","userTown":"someUserTown","userDistrict":"someUserDistrict","userState":"someUserState","userCountry":"someUserCountry","userListOfRoleNames":["SuperUser"],"userLastLoginTimestamp":1436372833064,"userLastLogoutTimestamp":0,"version":1}

I 2015-07-08 21:57:33.147

com.applix.imedipro.serverapp.dao.DaoUser <init>: This object is       com.applix.imedipro.serverapp.dao.DaoUser@1cf2d14

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.148

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl initialiseLevel1Cache: Level 1 Cache of type "soft" initialised

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.148

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl <init>: Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda" opened for datastore "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager@1b71125" with txn="org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl@26b3fb"

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.148

org.datanucleus.transaction.Transaction <init>: Transaction created [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid=

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.148

org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalBegin: Transaction begun for ObjectManager org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda (optimistic=true)

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.148

com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection <init>: Created ManagedConnection using DatastoreService = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl@f2343a

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.148

org.datanucleus.transaction.Transaction enlistResource: Running enlist operation on resource: com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreXAResource@735d7f, error code TMNOFLAGS and transaction: [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid=

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.151

com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreXAResource start: Started datastore transaction: 4261602282148180867

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.152

org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection:  Connection added to the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@4445f6 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@842f22]

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.157

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl getObjectFromLevel1Cache: Object with id "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM" not found in Level 1 cache [cache size = 0]

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.157

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl putObjectIntoLevel1Cache: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@4d3c7d" (id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NNNNYNNNNNNNNNN]")

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.158

org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@4d3c7d" (id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM") is having the value in field "userListOfRoleNames" replaced by a SCO wrapper

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.158

org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.ArrayList initialise: Created SCO wrapper for object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@4d3c7d" field "userListOfRoleNames" with 1 entries, using options="cached,allowNulls"

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.158

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl enlistInTransaction: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@4d3c7d" (id="ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM") enlisted in transactional cache

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.158

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl getObjectFromLevel2Cache: Object with id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM" taken from Level 2 cache (fields="[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]", version="") - represented as "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@4d3c7d"

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.158

org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@4d3c7d" (id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM") has a lifecycle change : "P_CLEAN"->"P_NONTRANS"

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.158

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl evictFromTransaction: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@4d3c7d" (id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM") being evicted from transactional cache

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.159

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl removeObjectFromLevel2Cache: Object with id="ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM" removed from Level 2 cache

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.159

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl persistObjectInternal: Making object persistent : "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9"

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.159

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl enlistInTransaction: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" (id="org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference@14fbfca") enlisted in transactional cache

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.159

org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager makePersistent: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" has been marked for persistence but its actual persistence to the datastore will be delayed due to use of optimistic transactions or "delayDatastoreOperationsUntilCommit"

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.159

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl putObjectIntoLevel1Cache: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" (id="org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference@14fbfca") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY]")

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.159

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl flushInternalWithOrdering: ObjectManager.internalFlush() process started using ordered flush - 1 dirty objects

I 2015-07-08 21:57:33.159

com.applix.imedipro.serverapp.dao.DaoUser updateUser: existing version = 1

I 2015-07-08 21:57:33.159

com.applix.imedipro.serverapp.dao.DaoUser updateUser: param version = 1

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.160

org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection:  Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@4445f6 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@842f22]

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.160

org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection: Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@4445f6 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@842f22]

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.160

org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection: Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@4445f6 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@842f22]

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.160

org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection: Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@4445f6 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@842f22]

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.160

org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection: Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@4445f6 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@842f22]

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.160

com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils putEntitiesIntoDatastore: Putting entity of kind User with key User("someUserIden") as {USER_TOWN[someUserTown], USER_AREA[someUserArea], USER_DISTRICT[someUserDistrict], VERSION[1], USER_Street[someUserStreet], USER_NAME[someUserName], USER_MOBILE[2222222222], userListOfRoleNames[[SuperUser]], USER_LAST_LOGOUT_TIMESTAMP[0], USER_COUNTRY[someUserCountry], USER_STATE[someUserState], USER_PASSWORD[someUserPassword], USER_LAST_LOGIN_TIMESTAMP[1436372833064], }

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.164

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl replaceObjectId: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" (id="org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference@14fbfca") being changed to be referenced by id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM" in Level 1 cache

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.164

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl replaceObjectId: Object  "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" (id="org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference@14fbfca") enlisted in transactional cache is now enlisted using id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM"

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.164

org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection:  Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@4445f6 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@842f22]

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.164

org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" (id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM") is having the value in field "userListOfRoleNames" replaced by a SCO wrapper

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.164

org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.ArrayList initialise: Created SCO wrapper for object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" field "userListOfRoleNames" with 1 entries, using options="cached,allowNulls"

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.164

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl flushInternal:  ObjectManager.internalFlush() process finished

I 2015-07-08 21:57:33.164

com.applix.imedipro.serverapp.dao.DaoUser updateUser: new version = 1

I 2015-07-08 21:57:33.164

com.applix.transactions.TranxUtility postTransaction: EM is open

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.165

org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalPreCommit: Transaction committing for ObjectManager org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.165

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl flushInternalWithOrdering: ObjectManager.internalFlush() process started using ordered flush - 0 dirty objects

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.165

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl flushInternal: ObjectManager.internalFlush() process finished

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.165

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl putObjectsIntoLevel2Cache: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" (id="ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM") added to Level 2 cache (fields="[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]", version="1")

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.165

org.datanucleus.transaction.Transaction commit: Committing [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid=

I 2015-07-08 21:57:33.165

com.applix.transactions.TranxUtility postTransaction: transaction is active

I 2015-07-08 21:57:33.165

com.applix.transactions.TranxUtility postTransaction: About to start committing the transaction

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.190

com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreXAResource commit: Committed datastore transaction: 4261602282148180867

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.191

org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$1 managedConnectionPostClose: Connection removed from the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@4445f6 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@842f22]

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.191

org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" (id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM") has a lifecycle change : "P_NEW"->"P_NONTRANS"

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.191

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl evictFromTransaction: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" (id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM") being evicted from transactional cache

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.191

org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl commit: Transaction committed in 26 ms

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.191

org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager detach: Detaching object from persistence : "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" (depth=0)

I 2015-07-08 21:57:33.191

com.applix.transactions.TranxUtility postTransaction: Transaction committed

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.192

org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager unwrapSCOField: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" (id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM") is having the SCO wrapper in field "userListOfRoleNames" replaced by the unwrapped value

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.192

org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState: Object "com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9" (id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM") has a lifecycle change : "P_NONTRANS"->"DETACHED_CLEAN"

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.192

org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager disconnect: Disconnecting com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9 from StateManager[pc=com.applix.imedipro.entity.User@be62e9, lifecycle=DETACHED_CLEAN]

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.192

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl removeObjectFromLevel1Cache: Object with id="com.applix.imedipro.entity.User:ahJzfmF0LWltZWRpcHJvLWJldGFyFwsSBFVzZXIiDW5pbWVzaF9wYXJtYXIM" being removed from Level 1 cache [current cache size = 1]

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.192

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl disconnectObjectProvidersFromCache: Level 1 Cache cleared

D 2015-07-08 21:57:33.192

org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl close: Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@989fda" closed

I 2015-07-08 21:57:33.192

com.applix.transactions.TranxUtility postTransaction: Entity Manager cleared
```

Comment: new log with .level=ALL added. Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: The log is truncated on column width. Also identify WHERE in this log is the merge called, because you can easily dump a statement into the log just before your merge and hence see what statements relate to your persistence code. And see the state of the object you pass in (which would also be logged). Maybe it isn't detached ...

Comment: Thank Neil, for your response. So if I understand it correctly, do I first have to detach the object and then merge it? In the meantime, I will try and affix the "full-width" log.

Comment: The full-width log is affixed.

Comment: Do the other fields that are changed in `paramUser` get saved to the database? As a test, in your code, try modifying the `existingUser` object fields after you have found it and then `merge()` it instead.

Comment: Hey Duncan, thanks. Changes made to fields on the UI are indeed showing up in the DB. I performed the test that you suggested. Enforced a value in a field of "exisitngUser" just before "merge"--> had no effect on "version". Extended this test further. Enforced a value in a field of "paramUser" just before "merge"--> had no effect "version" (i.e., the value in "version" remained at 1).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after 12 hours, found as answer.

Here is the code that DID work:

```
public  synchronized    User    updateUser  (User   paramUser)
                        throws  Exception   {
    User    user    =   null;

    user    =   getUserByUserIden(paramUser.getUserIden());
    user.setUserPassword(paramUser.getUserPassword());
    user.setUserName(paramUser.getUserName());
    user.setUserMobile(paramUser.getUserMobile());
    user.setUserStreet(paramUser.getUserStreet());
    user.setUserArea(paramUser.getUserArea());
    user.setUserTown(paramUser.getUserTown());
    user.setUserDistrict(paramUser.getUserDistrict());
    user.setUserState(paramUser.getUserState());
    user.setUserCountry(paramUser.getUserCountry());
    user.setUserListOfRoleNames(paramUser.getUserListOfRoleNames());
    user.setUserLastLoginTimestamp(paramUser.getUserLastLoginTimestamp());
    user.setUserLastLogoutTimestamp(paramUser.getUserLastLogoutTimestamp());

    user    =   tu.getEM().merge(user);

    return user;
}
```

In other words, following is the sequence that works:

- Read the "User" entity in "user", based on the key value passed in "paramUser"
- Copy all the fields from "paramUser" into "user"
- merge "user"

Comment: or alternatively, detach the object and pass it to other parts of your application, updating fields as you go, and then pass it back to the persistence layer and call em.merge.